# ImageButton is cut off?

Tags: java, android, image, android-layout, android-activity

I have an image button in my Main Activity java class. This image button was working fine before, but now I have added code to change the picture of it:

```
if (getMuteStatus()) { //MUTE
        mutebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.unmutebutton);
    } else {
        mutebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.mutebutton);
    }
```

Now, the image succesfuly changes its picture when I do the task, but it is completely cut off. This happened only after adding this code to it, which shouldn't have changed anything. I tried to fix it by removing my images from my `drawable` folder to my `mitmap` folder, but the same issue persisted:

[image]

Now the image is weirdly cut off. It's as if there is a square image that has been zoomed in x100, and we are seeing that blown up version of it. How can I fix this? After searching the web for an hour, the only thing I found was the mitmap movement, but even that isn't working!

Thanks,

Rich

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this code to your xml file:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

**FIT_CENTER:** The source completely fits inside the container.

Comment: Thanks so much Parth. What does this xml code do? I marked you best answer and liked your answer.

Comment: can't get it to your question: What does this xml code do?

Comment: And I have answered one of your question that you have asked now

Comment: I mean, what does fitCenter do? What was the issue with the code earlier?

Comment: I have edited the answer, it just used for the fits your image in the center position.

Comment: Without this my image was being cutted inside ImageButton when I reduced the ImageButton size (using android:layout_width and android:layout_height). With this line of code the image fits in the center and no matter how small my ImageButton is the android:src follows the size of the button.